# Should the ActionBar be handled on Fragments or on the Activity?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-listfragment

I am making a shopping list app, and I have two `Fragments`, a `ProductListFragment` and a `ShoppingListFragment`. I have `ActionBar` buttons to add elements to the `List` on `ProductListFragment`. My question is, should I handle these buttons on the Fragment or on the Activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should allow your Activity to handle the events of your fragments.  This allows you flexibility in your design so that you can reuse your fragments in other Activities down the line.  [Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#EventCallbacks) is a great example of how to accomplish this using event callbacks. Good luck.