# It's impossible to pass data between these two fragment

Tags: android, string, interface, android-fragments

I'm going insane!! 
I don't manage to pass data from a fragment(A) to an another fragment(B).
I read about using a public interface... and it seems to work, but i don't understand how to use this method.

Fragment(A)

```
package it.anddev.pagertabs;
public class Page1Fragment extends Fragment {

String Str;
OnDataPass dataPasser;

Class Senddata extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

   @Override
   protected void onPreExecute() {

                            // do something [...]

   }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

                             // do something [...]

           dataPasser.onDataPass(result_array.toString());

    }

      return null;

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

                             // do something [...]

    }};



@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
  super.onAttach(activity);
  dataPasser = (OnDataPass) activity;

}

public interface OnDataPass {
    public void onDataPass(String data);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                       // do something [...]

  Button Avanti = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.sendbutton);
  Avanti.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View view) {
               //mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1, true);
               new Senddata().execute();
           }
            });
```

FragmentB

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {


  if (container == null) {
     return null;
  }

  View view = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.page2,container,false);

  Button mostra = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.mostrabutton);

           // String str = i need to get string from "public void onDataPass"

  mostra.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
           //mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1, true);
           Log.d("IT WORKS", str);
       }
        });


  return view;
}

@Override
public void onDataPass(final String data) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
Log.d("okkkkkk", "" + data);

}
```

So finally, how i can get the string from the public void in the fragmentB? 
Thanks

Comment: Looking at the code, when sending data from A to B you should be getting a NullPointerException in AsyncTask: dataPasser.onDataPass(result_array.toString()); ... as `result_array` is null in your call case. true?

Comment: yes because "do something [...]" stands for some other lines of code... is not important where result_array came from! I wants to know how to recuperate the string "data" in the fragmentB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider my 2 fragments A and B, and Suppose I need to pass data from B to A.

Then create an interface in B, and pass the data to the Main Activity. There create another interface and pass data to fragment A.

Sharing a small example:

Fragment A looks like

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment implements InterfaceDataCommunicatorFromActivity {
    public InterfaceDataCommunicatorFromActivity interfaceDataCommunicatorFromActivity;
    String data;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateData(String data) {
        this.data = data;
        //data is updated here which is from fragment B
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            interfaceDataCommunicatorFromActivity = (InterfaceDataCommunicatorFromActivity) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement InterfaceDataCommunicatorFromActivity");
        }
    }

}
```

FragmentB looks like

```
class FragmentB extends Fragment {
    public InterfaceDataCommunicator interfaceDataCommunicator;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // call this inorder to send Data to interface
        interfaceDataCommunicator.updateData("data");
    }

    public interface InterfaceDataCommunicator {
        public void updateData(String data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            interfaceDataCommunicator = (InterfaceDataCommunicator) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement InterfaceDataCommunicator");
        }
    }

}
```

Main Activity is

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements InterfaceDataCommunicator {
    public InterfaceDataCommunicatorFromActivity interfaceDataCommunicatorFromActivity;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void updateData(String data) {
        interfaceDataCommunicatorFromActivity.updateData(data);
    }

    public interface InterfaceDataCommunicatorFromActivity {
        public void updateData(String data);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Most easiest way is create a static variable in first fragment and use this variable in second fragment.

Comment: if you have to share small amount of data then you can easily use static variables (for example some kind of variables or one or two objects)

Answer (score 0):

Use a public interface to pass the String through the Activity that is containing the fragments.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18617490/should-the-actionbar-be-handled-on-fragments-or-on-the-activity/18618077#18618077) is simular question and solution with more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Consider 2 fragments A and B and suppose I need to pass data from B to A.

Then create an interface in B, and pass the data to the Activity. From there you can call in A `getActivity()` to get the information.

Example:

### Activity is:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements InterfaceDataCommunicator {
    public static String data;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void updateData(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

}
```

### Fragment A:

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getActivity().data;//receive data

        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }

}
```

### Fragment B:

```
class FragmentB extends Fragment {
    public InterfaceDataCommunicator interfaceDataCommunicator;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        interfaceDataCommunicator.updateData(/*the String to send*/); //send data
    }

    public interface InterfaceDataCommunicator {
        public void updateData(String data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            interfaceDataCommunicator = (InterfaceDataCommunicator) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement InterfaceDataCommunicator");
        }
    }

}
```